# MySQL live Query

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder if someone can help i am trying to incorporate a live search into my website, I have found a tutorial and the appearance side of things is now working, could someone please tell me how i can edit the follow PHP to pull information from only one table.

Table - movies
Fields to echo for each result - Movie, description, Image

At the moment it is pulling information from 2 tables successfully one displays the content of the search the other provides information for category dividers, What i need is to remove the category aspect and pull information from the a single table.

Apologies my PHP knowledge is very limited, hope this best describes the problem.

```
<p id="searchresults">
<?php
// PHP5 Implementation - uses MySQLi.
// mysqli('localhost', 'yourUsername', 'yourPassword', 'yourDatabase');
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'yourUsername', 'yourPassword', 'yourDatabase');

if(!$db) {
    // Show error if we cannot connect.
    echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
} else {

    // Is there a posted query string?
    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
        $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

        // Is the string length greater than 0?
        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM search s INNER JOIN categories c ON s.cat_id = c.cid WHERE name LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' ORDER BY cat_id LIMIT 8");

            if($query) {
                // While there are results loop through them - fetching an Object.

                // Store the category id
                $catid = 0;
                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                    if($result->cat_id != $catid) { // check if the category changed
                        echo '<span class="category">'.$result->cat_name.'</span>';
                        $catid = $result->cat_id;
                    }
                    echo '<a href="'.$result->url.'">';
                    echo '<img src="search_images/'.$result->img.'" alt="" />';

                    $name = $result->name;
                    if(strlen($name) > 35) { 
                        $name = substr($name, 0, 35) . "...";
                    }                       
                    echo '<span class="searchheading">'.$name.'</span>';

                    $description = $result->desc;
                    if(strlen($description) > 80) { 
                        $description = substr($description, 0, 80) . "...";
                    }

                    echo '<span>'.$description.'</span></a>';
                }
                echo '<span class="seperator"><a href="http://www.marcofolio.net/sitemap.html" title="Sitemap">Nothing interesting here? Try the sitemap.</a></span><br class="break" />';
            } else {
                echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
            }
        } else {
            // Dont do anything.
        } // There is a queryString.
    } else {
        echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
    }
}
?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
SELECT * FROM search s INNER JOIN categories c ON s.cat_id = c.cid WHERE name LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' ORDER BY cat_id LIMIT 8
```

with

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movie LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' ORDER BY movie LIMIT 8
```

would be a good start.

Can you carry on from there?

Aside - you wrote 'Movie' for the field name in your description above - I've used a lower case 'M' so you may need to change it.

[edit] In reply to comment #1:

Let's start off simple - replace `if ($query) { ... }` with

```
if ($query) {
    while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) { // this line loops through all the results
        echo '<img src="search_images/'.$result->image.' />'; // check capital I on 'image'
        echo '<strong>'.$result->movie.'</strong>';
        echo $result->description.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Basically, you just put `$result->myFieldName` inside of the while loop to get the data out you want.
Hopefully that should be enough get you going =]

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, the code that follows is confusing me as its making reference to the other table I'm unsure what to remove?

Answer (score 0):

I guess:

```
<p id="searchresults">
<?php
// PHP5 Implementation - uses MySQLi.
// mysqli('localhost', 'yourUsername', 'yourPassword', 'yourDatabase');
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'yourUsername', 'yourPassword', 'yourDatabase');

if(!$db) {
    // Show error if we cannot connect.
    echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to the database.';
} else {

    // Is there a posted query string?
    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
        $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

        // Is the string length greater than 0?
        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {
            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM movies  WHERE Movie LIKE '%" . $queryString . "%' ORDER BY Movie LIMIT 8");

            if($query) {
                // While there are results loop through them - fetching an Object.


                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                    echo '<a href="'.$result->url.'">';
                    echo '<img src="search_images/'.$result->img.'" alt="" />';

                    $name = $result->movie;
                    if(strlen($name) > 35) { 
                        $name = substr($name, 0, 35) . "...";
                    }                       
                    echo '<span class="searchheading">'.$name.'</span>';

                    $description = $result->description;
                    if(strlen($description) > 80) { 
                        $description = substr($description, 0, 80) . "...";
                    }

                    echo '<span>'.$description.'</span></a>';
                }
                echo '<span class="seperator"><a href="http://www.marcofolio.net/sitemap.html" title="Sitemap">Nothing interesting here? Try the sitemap.</a></span><br class="break" />';
            } else {
                echo 'ERROR: There was a problem with the query.';
            }
        } else {
            // Dont do anything.
        } // There is a queryString.
    } else {
        echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
    }
}
?>
</p>
```